# TextView size and scrolling issue (Android)

Tags: android, textview

I just have a TextView in a ScrollView which can contain different text. The size of the text is always different too. The problem is that on different screens this TextView can be fully placed on screen or not. I want to center the text vertically on screen. If the text is small, it works fine. But if the text length is bigger than the screen can contain, it just loses the beginning of text and also the strange empty space after text appears. How can I fix this?

The attribute `gravity` of textview just centers the text horizontally, but `layout_gravity` does that strange thing I described above. If I remove `layout_gravity`, all the text looks good, but it's at the top of the scrollview =(

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/llbuttons"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: do you have any other view in your layout like "llbuttons" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of `ScrollView` you need to add 2 attributes in xml `android:maxLines` and `android:scrollbars="vertical"`

**XML**

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/babySitterDescTxtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s."
        android:textColor="@color/fragment_page_txt_color"
        android:typeface="sans" />
```

in **JAVA**

```
babySitterDescTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.babySitterDescTxtView);
babySitterDescTxtView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView can scroll the text itself. You don't need to use ScrollView:

```
<TextView 
    android:text="Some text..." 
    android:id="@+id/my_textview_id" 
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"  
    android:scrollbars="vertical">
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </ScrollView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/llbuttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```