# ScrollView cannot scroll

Tags: android, scrollview

I have a simple ScrollView and a TextView inside it. None of the solutions here helped me so I am posting my own code;

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/note" />

</ScrollView>
```

Here, `@string/note` is a quite long string that holds much more height than 100dp. So, when limited to 100dp, ScrollView must work, but it is not scrolling at all. What is the problem?

Comment: try by changing the textview layout_height to match_parent

Comment: Set the TextView's `layout_height="wrap_content"`.

Comment: None of these worked. It's still unscrollable.

Comment: And whoever negative voted this post please explain by what reason may you have downvoted a post that has no solution yet on SA, plus does not violate any asking convention. If you could explain, I could be more careful about the point that I am possibly missing.

Comment: try to enable vertical scroll in textview instead of taken ScrollView as parent.

Answer (score 0):

Because your TextView and ScrollView has same height. ScrollView no need to scroll here.
You must change height of your TextView to wrap-content like this:

```
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="@string/note" />

</ScrollView>
```

if it doesn't work. Try remove the ScrollView and set android:scrollbars = "vertical" property to your TextView
And in your code add: yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())

Comment: I have tried wrap_content and match_parent, but ScrollView still does not scroll.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `ScrollView` you need to add 2 attributes in xml `android:maxLines` and `android:scrollbars="vertical"` in that `TextView`

XML

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/babySitterDescTxtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&apos;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s."
        android:textColor="@color/fragment_page_txt_color"
        android:typeface="sans" />
```

in JAVA

```
babySitterDescTxtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.babySitterDescTxtView);
babySitterDescTxtView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

You can check [TextView size and scrolling issue (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076033/textview-size-and-scrolling-issue-android/25076993#25076993)